# jquery cancel click action after a script

Tags: jquery, click

I have a script showing the content of tabs. This part works fine but when the user clicks on the link the browser seems to execute the click and bring the user back to the top of the page.
I have a return false into the script to cancel ent click and have also tried with event.preventDefault() but no luck there either.
Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
                            <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
                </ul>


                <div class="tab_container">

                            <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">

                               <div id="content">
                                <h2>Tab 1</h2>
                                <p>Tab 1 info here </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
                                 <h2>Tab 2</h2>
                                <p>This is tab 2 here</p><br />



                                   <p>This is tab 2 here</p><br />
                            </div>


                            <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
                                <h2>Tab 3</h2>
                                <p>tab 3 info here</p>                   
                            </div>

                </div>
```

And here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//When page loads...
$(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content


//attribute an idea to each tab
$('.tabs li').each(function(i) {
var thisId = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
thisId = thisId.substring(1,thisId.length) + '_top';
$(this).attr("id",thisId);
}); 



function changeTab(activeTab)
{


            $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
            $(activeTab + '_top').addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab, using the id created at document load

            $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

            $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content



}



//On Click Event
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

        //call above function
        changeTab($(this).find("a").attr("href"));
    //event.preventDefault();   
    return false;

});
```

});

Answer (score 3):

You apply the click event to LI element, if you want `return false;` to work, you should apply onclick to A tag.

```
$("ul.tabs li a").click(function() {
  changeTab($(this).attr("href"));
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes that would make sense but even after correction I still have the problem, here is what I have changed:

Answer (score 0):

Change your on click event to this:

```
$("ul.tabs li a").click(function() {
    //call above function
    changeTab($(this).attr("href"));
    //event.preventDefault();   
    return false;

});
```

Comment: Yes that's what I have but the problem is still there.